# JSF cascading drop down

Tags: jsf-2

I am experiencing a weird behavior. I have cascading requirement in my project so I did a small code snippet in my personal laptop which worked but the same thing did not work in my project explaining the scenarios below:

Bean code:

```
/**
 * LoginBean.java
 */
package com.tutorial;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

public class LoginBean
{
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String dropDownValue;
    private String dropDownTwoValue;
    Set<SelectItem> testDropDown = new HashSet<SelectItem>();
    Set<SelectItem> testDropDownTwo = new HashSet<SelectItem>();
    Set<SelectItem> hhs = new HashSet<SelectItem>();

    public String getDropDownValue() {
        System.out.println("getttttttttttttttttttt");
        return dropDownValue;
    }


    public void setDropDownValue(String dropDownValue) {
        this.dropDownValue = dropDownValue;
    }


    public String getDropDownTwoValue() {
        return dropDownTwoValue;
    }


    public void setDropDownTwoValue(String dropDownTwoValue) {
        this.dropDownTwoValue = dropDownTwoValue;
    }


    public Set<SelectItem> getTestDropDown() {
        testDropDown.add(new SelectItem("One"));
        testDropDown.add(new SelectItem("Two"));
        testDropDown.add(new SelectItem("Three"));
        testDropDown.add(new SelectItem("Four"));
        return testDropDown;
    }


    public Set<SelectItem> getTestDropDownTwo() {
        return testDropDownTwo;
    }


    public void setTestDropDownTwo(List<SelectItem> testDropDownTwo) {

    }


    public void setTestDropDown(Set<SelectItem> testDropDown) {

        this.testDropDown = testDropDown;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName (final String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getPassword ()
    {
        return password;
    }


    public void setPassword (final String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String submit() {
        // Do your thing here.
        // ...
        System.out.println("****LoginBean***submit***");
        return "login";
    }
    public void changeDropDownOne() {
        System.out.println("^^^"+getDropDownTwoValue()+"^^^^^");
        String dropDownTwoValueTempValue = getDropDownTwoValue();
        String dp = getDropDownValue();
        if(dp != null) {
            System.out.println("kggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggetTestDropDownTwo********************************"+dp);
            if(dp.equalsIgnoreCase("One")) {
                testDropDownTwo = new HashSet<SelectItem>();
                if(dropDownTwoValueTempValue!=null && !dropDownTwoValueTempValue.equalsIgnoreCase("****select***")) {
                    testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem(dropDownTwoValueTempValue));
                }  else {
                    testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("****select***"));
                }
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("One - One"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("One - Two"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("One - Three"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("One - Four"));
            } else if(dp.equalsIgnoreCase("Two")) {
                testDropDownTwo = new HashSet<SelectItem>();
                if(dropDownTwoValueTempValue!=null && !dropDownTwoValueTempValue.equalsIgnoreCase("****select***")) {
                    testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem(dropDownTwoValueTempValue));
                }  else {
                    testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("****select***"));
                } 
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Two - One"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Two - Two"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Two - Three"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Two - Four"));
            }else if(dp.equalsIgnoreCase("Three")) {
                testDropDownTwo = new HashSet<SelectItem>();
                if(dropDownTwoValueTempValue!=null && !dropDownTwoValueTempValue.equalsIgnoreCase("****select***")) {
                    testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem(dropDownTwoValueTempValue));
                }  else {
                    testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("****select***"));
                } 
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Three - One"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Three - Two"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Three - Three"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Three - Four"));
            }else {
                testDropDownTwo = new HashSet<SelectItem>();
                if(dropDownTwoValueTempValue!=null && !dropDownTwoValueTempValue.equalsIgnoreCase("****select***")) {
                    testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem(dropDownTwoValueTempValue));
                }  else {
                    testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("****select***"));
                } 
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Four - One"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Four - Two"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Four - Three"));
                testDropDownTwo.add(new SelectItem("Four - Four"));
            }
        }
        //return testDropDownTwo;
    }
}
```

XHTML Code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>

<h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces"/>

</h:head>

<body>

<h:form>

<h:selectOneMenu id="dropDownValue" value="#{loginBean.dropDownValue}" >
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="****select***" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{loginBean.testDropDown}"/>
                            <f:ajax render="testDropDownTwo"  listener="#{loginBean.changeDropDownOne}" /> 
                        </h:selectOneMenu>

 <h:selectOneMenu id="testDropDownTwo" value="#{loginBean.dropDownTwoValue}" >
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="****select***" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{loginBean.testDropDownTwo}" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>

</h:form>

</body>

</html>
```

In my office system when I change the first drop down the control is going to changeDropDownOne and the testDropDownTwo is getting updated but the value is not reflecting the second drop down.

Please help me int his regrard

Thanks

KK

Comment: You dont need to include <h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces"/>

Comment: with out that its not working i guess let me check and get back to u (after two hours). but thats not the problem i think the listner method is getting called but the it is not getting applied to the second list.